# Make iPhone app available for iPad download

Tags: ipad, store

I have a iphone app that is in the app store and can be downloaded.
The app doesn't show up in downloads for an ipad in the app store.  Is there an option in the app specs on itunes connect to set this option?  Do I have to upload a new version that will work on both iphone and ipad?

Answer (score 1):

All iPhone apps should be available for download on the iPad. The only way it wouldn't be downloadable by an iPad is if you have some sort of constraint in your app's main info plist that says your app requires, for example, a camera.

Edit: You can post your info.plist file if you'd like and I'll take a look at it.